# How to change wordpress "document root"

Tags: wordpress

I've installed wordpress in "/wordpress" and not in the site root, so the wordpress site is now accessible only from http://www.mysite.com/wordpress/.
How can I move wordpress to the site root (so it can be accessible from http://www.mysite.com) and make it work correctly?

Thanks

Comment: [Check this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you locked out on your site? you might need to modify the database to point to the new url

Follow these steps
https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/

the database you need to modify are  siteurl, home in the wp_options table
http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Thank you! I'm following the instructions on the links you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, in the wp-admin, settings change site address to `http://www.mysite.com` and in the server move your wordpress files to the document root.

Comment: You would also need to modify your database and change all mysite.com/wordpress references to mysite.com